# find complete object in list of objects

Tags: vb.net, linq

is it possible to find a complete object in list of objects?

```
dim list1 as list(of class1) = alist
dim x as class1
```

how to find x in list1 if it exists **without** comparing a single property like ID ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - do you mean you want to compare every property within x except the ID? A full example would really help...

Answer (score 2):

The Contains method will return true if the element is in the list.

```
dim list1 as list(of class1) = alist
dim x as class1   

list1.Contains(x)
```